# Using Pytest + django, is there a way for fixtures with different scope, work transactionally while sharing DB?

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-django

An Example code (which does not work)

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def my_method_user(db):
    user = User(name="method_user").save()
    return user


@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def my_class_user(db):
    user = User(name="class_user").save()
    return user


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("my_class_user")
class TestClass:
    def test_user_count(self):
        assert len(User.objects.all()) == 1

    def test_user_count_2(self, my_method_user):
        assert len(User.objects.all()) == 2
```

However, doing this (or anything similar where I tried to access DB directly through queryset etc) basically always gives me `ScopeMistmatch`.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is

- Create a User that will be "globally" used within the class - fixture with class scope (or maybe rather, some rows that were "setup" in prior to performing a test for class)
- In some of the test functions, I would like a user to be created temporarily (but with a certain condition, thus I hope to use fixture). When the function tested is done, the user is automatically removed.

Later on, the datas might be more nested than simple class-function, the entire 5 layers might be all used. So rows that were created by class-scoped fixtures should also be deleted after, but that were created by module/package/session should stay

I've researched about using django_db_blocker.unblock() trying to avoid scopemismatch and keep datas throughout multiple tests, however it gives me a problem where the datas are not being removed after the tests are done (unless I remove them manually, which may be quite inaccurate).

Am i fundamentally wrong about how I'm supposed to use pytest/fixture? or am I missing something? Is there a different way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you seen pytest's determine scope? https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/fixtures.html?highlight=determine_scope#dynamic-scope and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59619621/pytest-change-fixture-scope-at-run-time